# Rails full_messages missing label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

For some reason rails full_messages is missing labels and simply contains the error without any clue as to which field it relates to:

```
[3] pry(#<Spree::CheckoutController>)> @order.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fce1caa8218
 @base=
  #<Spree::Order id: 87, number: "R442456123", item_total: #<BigDecimal:7fce1c57a4a8,'0.6495E2',18(36)>, total: #<BigDecimal:7fce1c5cd0e0,'0.6495E2',18(27)>, state: "address", adjustment_total: #<BigDecimal:7fce1c5cd270,'0.0',9(27)>, user_id: 57, completed_at: nil, bill_address_id: nil, ship_address_id: nil, payment_total: #<BigDecimal:7fce1cb184a0,'0.0',9(27)>, shipping_method_id: nil, shipment_state: nil, payment_state: nil, email: "nick@1-night.co.nz", special_instructions: nil, created_at: "2014-10-10 09:47:21", updated_at: "2014-10-10 09:47:24", currency: "USD", last_ip_address: "127.0.0.1", created_by_id: 57, channel: "spree", tax_total: #<BigDecimal:7fce1cb217d0,'0.0',9(27)>>,
 @messages=
  {:"bill_address.phone"=>["can't be blank"],
   :"ship_address.phone"=>["can't be blank"]}>
[4] pry(#<Spree::CheckoutController>)> @order.errors.full_messages
=> ["can't be blank", "can't be blank"]
```

I have added the attributes in en.yml - How do I get full messages to contain the model name ie: `["Billing address phone can't be blank", "Shipping address phone can't be blank"]`

Using the following:

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'spree', '2.1.4'
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this was an issue of having (for a reason long forgotten) the following in my en.yml.

```
  errors:
    format: "%{message}"
```

After removing it labels show correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you added the attributes in en.yml file is wrong. You should do it this way:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      spree/order/bill_address:
        phone: Billing address phone
      spree/order/ship_address:
        phone: Shipping address phone
```

Comment: Actually spree core already have these translations so I deleted my entries. But since they already exist in spree_core/config/en.yml it probably isnt it. Thanks for your help tho.